# Python prints "..." in very large output

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to print something big in python and instead of getting the whole result i get parts of it with "..." in the middle. Any ideas how to get the whole of it?

e.g.

```
'8.881386032' '5.737972827' '3.355746972' ..., '2.827335059', '2.598858336' '2.69954686'
```

The code is:

```
transposedMatrix = np.transpose(data)
print (transposedMatrix)
```

I am already converting it into a string and i get the same thing when i am writing in  files

Comment: Could you show the involved code?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Share some code...

Comment: Are you using `numpy`?

Comment: Without any code, it's hard to understand what's happening...

Comment: This is the code 

transposedMatrix = np.transpose(data)
print (str(transposedMatrix))

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For `numpy`, call:

```
import sys
import numpy

numpy.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxint)
```

to raise the threshold to infinity. See the [`numpy.set_printoptions()` documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html) for more details.

For Python 3, use `sys.maxsize` instead:

```
numpy.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)
```

Comment: are you sure this exists in python 3?

Comment: @user1663930: ah, missed that you are using Python 3; `maxsize` is what you want instead then.

Comment: python 2.7 and not using numpy, just want to dump a long string.    write(str(filecontents)) prints/writes first 32 lines, "...", and last 32 lines, grrr.  How to turn off "..." elision of strings in 2.7.

Comment: `type(obj)` => <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
`pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None, "display.max_columns", None)`