# Making dummy variables for days of week using sklearn DictVectorizer

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, dictvectorizer

I am preparing pricing data for linear regression. My features consist only of days of the week. My target is price. I've made a list of dictionaries of my data, just like the example in [sklearn 4.2.1](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html) Loading features from dicts. So the data structure is `[{'day': 'friday', 'price': 59}, {'day': 'saturday', 'price': 65}` and so on.

I used sklearn's DictVectorizer per the above link to dummy code the days of the week and convert the data structure to a list of lists (suitable for sklearn LinearRegression).

```
vec = DictVectorizer()
vec_fit = vec.fit_transform(my_data).toarray()
```

When I print vec_fit to see the data, I get the output below.

```
[[   0.    0.    0. ...,    0.    1.   59.]
 [   0.    0.    0. ...,    0.    0.   92.]
 [   1.    0.    0. ...,    0.    0.   92.]
 ...,
 [   0.    0.    1. ...,    0.    0.  181.]
 [   0.    0.    0. ...,    0.    0.  181.]
 [   0.    1.    0. ...,    0.    0.  181.]]
```

Can someone explain (a) the `...,` and (b) why there aren't 7 dummy variables for days of the week? In my example, the `...,` seems to cover Sunday and Thursday.

To check my features (per sklearn 4.2.1), I used the `get_feature_names` function.

```
vec.get_feature_names()

[u'day=Friday', u'day=Monday', u'day=Saturday', u'day=Sunday', 
 u'day=Thursday', u'day=Tuesday', u'day=Wednesday', 'price']
```

As shown from the output, all of the days seem to be appropriately represented. I am still confused re: (a) and (b) above. FYI, when I do `LinearRegression` I only get 6 coefficients (I am expecting 7; one for each day of week) Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are present there, just not shown when you print the `vec_fit`. Its the default behaviour of numpy when printing large arrays. Only first 3 and last 3 columns of the data are shown along with first 3 and last 3 rows.

```
[[   0.    0.    0. ...,    0.    1.   59.]
 [   0.    0.    0. ...,    0.    0.   92.]
 [   1.    0.    0. ...,    0.    0.   92.]
 ..., <=== This is for all intermediate data values present. Just not printed
 [   0.    0.    1. ...,    0.    0.  181.]
 [   0.    0.    0. ...,    0.    0.  181.]
 [   0.    1.    0. ...,    0.    0.  181.]]
```

You can confirm that all data exists by checking the shape of your array.

```
print(vec_fit.shape)
```

It should be `(n_rows, 8)`. The first value (`n_rows`) covers all your samples. The second value (`8`) covers your 7 dummy variables and 1 target variable.

If you want to print the full array, then please see these questions:

- [How to print the full NumPy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987694/how-to-print-the-full-numpy-array)
- [Python prints "..." in very large output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15364114/python-prints-in-very-large-output)

Comment: nice answer Vivek :)

Comment: Thank you! After posting, that thought popped in my mind. But then I made a test file with 10 features and when I printed I got 0 or 1 for all ten without the `...,`

Comment: @vintagedeek Did you make a list of list or a numpy array for test

Comment: I used the measurements example in sklearn 4.2.1. It is a list of dictionaries where each dictionary has a city and temperature key. I added cities such that there were 10 cities total. I then used `DictVectorizer` and made a numpy array. Essentially the same as I did for my pricing data. It seems that the `...,` within the features results from the overall length of the array as you said. I thought the overall length of the array only led to the `...,` that you highlighted in your answer.